# map() function not working in the class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have written the following codes but the console prompts an error that says **'this.state.result.map is not a function'** (in the 'return'). Just wondering if anyone has any idea what is wrong. Thanks!

```
       class App extends React.Component {

            constructor (props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    result: []
                }
            }

            componentDidMount(){

                const fetchGithub = (loginName) =>
                fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${loginName}/followers`)
                        .then(response => response.json());

                const processJson= () =>
                    fetchGithub('ericelliott')
                        .then(json => {
                                const userList = json.map(user => 
                                user.login
                                )
                            const result = userList.join(', ')
                            this.setState({result: result})
                        });

                processJson();

            }

            render(){  


                return (
                    <div>
                        {this.state.result.map(user => (
                            <div> 
                                <div>
                                    {user.login}
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        }
```

Comment: did you console.log in your `.then(json...` to make sure that json is an array, and that userList is an array, and that result is an array?

Comment: Add a log in render to check the value of `this.state.result`

Comment: [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a string from an array. You're changing the datatype of `results`. `map` no longer exists because its a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS map is reserved for Arrays, as you are using const result = userList.join(', '). This turns your result array to a string therefore map function is no longer available. Just remove that line.

Comment: You were right. Looks like I did turn the result into a string when I used join() hence the map() function would not work. It is working now! Thanks guys.